# Silverlight Data binding taking an age & locking gui

Tags: silverlight

We have a web service that picks up a report from a server and returns it to the Silverlight GUI. In the GUI we have an event handler that calls the following function:

```
        private void PopulateDataGrids()
    {
        try
        {                
            reportTitle = reportDataUtil.ReportHeader.Rows.First(r => r.Items[ReportTools.FIELDNAME_STRING].ToString() == ReportTools.FIELDVALUE_TITLE).Items[ReportTools.FIELDVALUE_STRING].ToString();

            dg_Report_Header.DataSource = reportDataUtil.ReportHeader;
            dg_Report_Header.CanUserSortColumns = false;
            dg_Report_Header.CanUserReorderColumns = false;
            dg_Report_Header.CanUserResizeColumns = true;
            dg_Report_Header.DataBind();
            dg_Report_Header.UpdateLayout();

            dg_Report_Detail.DataSource = reportDataUtil.ReportDetails;
            dg_Report_Detail.CanUserSortColumns = true;
            dg_Report_Detail.CanUserReorderColumns = true;
            dg_Report_Detail.CanUserResizeColumns = true;
            dg_Report_Detail.DataBind();
            dg_Report_Detail.UpdateLayout();

            //Hide the ElementID colmun
            if (dg_Report_Detail.Columns.Count > 0)
            {
                var col = dg_Report_Detail.Columns.FirstOrDefault(dc => dc.Header.ToString() == NetVisSolution.Reports.ReportTools.COLUMNNAME_ELEMENTID);
                if (col != null)
                {
                    col.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ClearResources();
            closeReportDataViewer();
            ErrorWindow.CreateNew("Unable to open selected report data, the file maybe corrupted or not \nin the server specified location.");
            //throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);                
        }
    }
```

Trouble is, the detail table can be 14000 rows long, taking up more than a megabyte. When such a report is loaded, the dg_Report_Detail.DataBind(); call takes several minutes and locks up the GUI.

Is there a simple way to do this asynchronously or in such a manner that the application remains responsive?

Thanks in advance,

--- Alistair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although DataGrid implements Row Virtualization, it can still spend a lot of time calculating the height of each row separately. Assigning a RowHeight will skip all those calculations.

```
  <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeight="20">
  </sdk:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late acknowledgement. Since implementing fixed height rows, it seems to be vastly more responsive.